# MySql query in php only returns the last result when encoded in json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I have a query (mysql) in php which when encoded to json only return the last result of the query however I am sure that the query returns more than one result:

```
$counter=0;
$reply=array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$stringQuery);;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $reply["json"]=$row;
        $counter++;
    }

    echo json_encode($reply);
} else {
    echo json_encode("0 results");
}
$conn->close();
```

when I stringify the result in javascript it only return the last entry of the table, or single result:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'SearchQuery.php',
    data: {
        'json': cond
    },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response["json"]));

    }
});
```

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$stringQuery);;` Extra semicolon

Comment: fixed it but the problem remains

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $reply[] = $row;
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    $counter++;
}
echo json_encode($reply);
```

Comment: if i do that and change the alert in javascript to: alert(JSON.stringify(response)); nothing happens, there is no alert; Somethings happens in the php, however no error is presented

Comment: @user1281678 Try `alert(JSON.stringify(response));` Because you are not sending data in `json` now

Comment: as I said before: if i do that and change the alert in javascript to: alert(JSON.stringify(response)); nothing happens, there is no alert; Somethings happens in the php, however no error is presented

Answer (score 1):

Try to change fetch_assoc() with fetch_array()

```
while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
       $reply[] = $row;
       $counter++;
}
echo json_encode($reply);
```

Or try:

```
while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
     $items.=<<<EOD
    {
"r": "{$row['yourfield']}",
},
EOD;
$counter++;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
    "response": [
        <?php echo $item;?>
    ]
}
```

Comment: $counter=0;
    //$reply=array();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$stringQuery);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $reply = array($counter => $row);
            //$reply[]=$row;
            $counter++;
        }

        echo json_encode($reply);
    } else {
        echo json_encode("0 results");
    }
    $conn->close(); this should work but it doesn't

Comment: where you have error??? in console.log???? Do you have changed the $row['yourfield'] with your fieldname???? Are you sure that EOD code is written correct without format???? check it because the code is correct!!! I use it in my function page.

Comment: sorry my mistake. I've tried it now and no error and in the alert() gives a response[], empty

Comment: this is the code I have put together with your else{

    $counter=0;
    //$reply=array();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$stringQuery);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
            $items.=<<<EOD
            {
                "r": "{$row['first_name']}",
            },
                EOD;
            $counter++;
        }

        header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
"response": [
<?php echo $item;?>
]
}
<?php
    } else {
        echo json_encode("0 results");
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?> 500 error

Comment: no you can't do that... before you have to insert the ELSE Code and in the response you write only { "response": [ <?php echo $item;?> ] } .... Now try this code without exceptions..

Comment: else{

    $counter=0;
    //$reply=array();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$stringQuery);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
            $items.=<<<EOD
            {
                "r": "{$row['user_role']}",
            },
                EOD;
            $counter++;
        }

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        }
    $conn->close();
    }
?>
{
"response": [
<?php echo $item;?>
]
} the problem remais, 500 error

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
$reply["json"]=$row;
```

in this line your last fetch row in while loop overwrite existing result so it is showing only last row as a result.

You  can try

```
$reply["json"][]=$row;
```

So at ajax in success function

```
alert(JSON.stringify(response["json"]));
```

you can have a data accessible via key name "json".

Comment: change contentType: "application/json" in ajax call